# How to use Distributed Object Cache in WebSphere 9 clustered environment

Tags: spring-boot, websphere, distributed

We have a WAS9 cluster with 2 servers. Our application relies on maintaining a list of objects. Application running on Server A creates an object and this object is not in scope of the Application instance on Server B. In order to replicate the object state we had attempted to enable Distributed Cache under Resources -> Cache Instances -> Object Cache Instance (scope is the cluster, provider is Default Dynamic Cache, cache replication enabled )

The state of the map is not shared between the servers. Application on server A places an object into the map and once reloaded and load balanced onto the server B, that object is not available in the map. The DistributedMap is behaving like a HashMap and does not get distributed at all.

Here is a simple code sample that shows how we attempt to use the Distributed Cache feature:

```
@RequestMapping("/test_object_map")
    @Async
    public String testObjectMap(@RequestParam(value="input", defaultValue="") String input) throws InterruptedException, NamingException, UnknownHostException {

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        DistributedObjectCache wasCashe = (DistributedObjectCache)ic.lookup(DIST_MAP_NAME);

        String testKey = "test_key";
        UseCase object = null;

        if(wasCashe.containsKey(testKey)) {
            object = (UseCase) wasCashe.get(testKey);

        } else {
            object = new UseCase();
            object.setSignature(" UC launched on " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
            wasCashe.put(testKey, object);

        }

        String status = "";

        if(object != null) {
            status = "host: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() + "; object state: " + object.getSignature() ;
        }

        return "[{\"message\": \"" + status + "\"}]";
    }
```

The behavior that we observer is that object is instantiated on "server_1" and when the request is balanced onto the "server_2" the object does not exist and a new instance of the object is created by "server_2". Instead we want to be able to share the state of the map between the two servers.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

In order to replicate content across WebSphere cluster members, a DynaCache cache instance has to be setup for replication, associated with a replication domain, and actually created in the JVM.  Defining a cache instance does not equate to creating the cache instance in the JVM.  The cache instance is created when ic.lookup() is invoked.

My guess is that server_2 has not created the cache instance when server_1 puts content into the cache instance and therefore content is not replicated.  I assume you have set the sharing policy to PUSH.

To force cache instance creation when the server starts, add custom property com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheConfig.createCacheAtServerStartup and set to true.  You can add this as a JVM custom property (affects all cache instances) or a custom property on the cache instance (affects only this cache instance).